# How to solve system of first order differential equations using Eulers method

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\sin(z*(2x+y))$$
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=e^{-0.05x}\cos(4y)$$
$$y(0) = -1, z(0) = 0$$
$$From \;x=0\:\:to\;x=7$$

Im trying to write a python script that solves this system of first order differential equations using Euler's method, but I don't really understand how to do it on paper at all. Can someone give me a step by step formula for solving it?

Comment: What do you know about Euler's method? There are several tutorials on youtube or elsewhere. Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Your system has the form $\begin{cases} \frac{{\rm d}u_{1}}{{\rm d}t}=\phi(t,u_{1},u_{2}),\\ \frac{{\rm d}u_{2}}{{\rm d}t}=\phi(t,u_{1},u_{2})\end{cases}\iff \frac{{\rm d}{\bf u}}{{\rm d}t}=\tilde{\phi}(t,u_{1},u_{2})$ so is a first-order system. So the Euler's method for the system is the extension of Euler's method for $\frac{{\rm d}u}{{\rm d}t}=\phi(t,u)$ first order differential equation with $u_{i+1}=u_{i}+h\phi(t_{i},u_{i})$ for example. Start with that and if you like show your work here.

Comment: @Andrei I understand how to use eulers to solve a single equation but from my current understanding im not sure how to apply it to a system of equations, like would I plug in a number for dz/dx and then use that answer for dy/dt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single equation, $$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x, y),\\y(0)=y_0$$you use a regular grid for $x$, with $x_n=nh$. Here $h$ is a step. Then you approximate the derivative by a finite difference:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}\approx\frac{y(x_{n+1})-y(x_n)}{(n+1)h-nh}$$
So if you know $y(x_n)$, you can immediately calculate $$y(x_{n+1})=y(x_n)+hf(x_n, y(x_n))$$
In your case you have a system of two equations. Instead of just $\frac{dy}{dx}$ now you have two derivatives.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y,z)\\\frac{dz}{dx}=g(x,y,z)$$
You apply the same steps as above, and you get $$
y(x_{n+1})=y(x_n)+hf(x_n, y(x_n),z(x_n))\\z(x_{n+1})=z(x_n)+hg(x_n, y(x_n),z(x_n))$$
So at every step you know the right hand side of the above equations and you can calculate $y$ and $z$ for the next step.

Comment: Thanks so much!